# How do I perform exact unit conversions with irrational conversion factors?

Tags: symbolic, units

Suppose I want to express $3h$ in units of $\hbar$ (where $h$ and $\hbar$ are the Planck constant and reduced Planck constant, respectively). By definition, $h = 2\pi\hbar$, but when I attempt this conversion using *Mathematica*'s built-in unit functions,

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[3, "PlanckConstant"], "ReducedPlanckConstant"]
    (* => 18.84956 ℏ *)
```

I obtain a non-exact (floating-point) result.

In general, I've observed that whenever I want to convert between two units for which there is an irrational (but exactly known) conversion factor (e.g. a multiple of $\pi^n$), *Mathematica*  fails to give the exact result. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[3, "PlanckConstant"], "ReducedPlanckConstant"] /.
  x_?NumericQ :> RootApproximant[x/Pi]*Pi
```

> Quantity[6*Pi, "ReducedPlanckConstant"]